# How Can I Use Dynamic Angualar Variable as Id for Showing Modal with Dynamic Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Actually My Aim is to Activate Modal Popup in ng-repeat with Dynamic ID**

Code Follows :-

```
    <div class="mpopup" id="{{obj.displayName}}"> <!-- id="{{obj.displayName}}" which i need to use as dynamic id in Below OnClick -->
          <div mypopupcontent></div> <!-- My Custom Directive which Shows the Model Dynamic  Content -->
        </div>

<!-- Button with Jquery OnCLick -->

    <button onclick="jQuery('#objdisplayName').modal('show');"> <i class="fa icon "></i> Show Popup</button>
```

Iam Having 'X' number of  different objects to display in 'X' different popup but the Dynamic angular Id Syntax({{obj.displayName}}) is not being accepted by Jquery

**Please give me an Idea about this Problem ..**

Thanks for the Help in Advance !!

Comment: You should not use jQuery like this with Angular. Moreover, you should not use inline handlers like this. The best you can do is not to use jQuery at all.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery for opening modal, neither your custom directive will get parsed, nor your interpolation will. You must switch to Angular UI, for things to work. Take a look [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)

Comment: @dfsq i see that iam trying for some quick output .. can you give some example @ this.question

Comment: You can use angualr. http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/#

Comment: Sadly Not Possible .. Using angular related UI is Best Practive